# Intent for sending text messages no longer working on Android 11

Tags: android, android-intent

When targeting Android 11 and using an Android 11 device (physical or emulator), the below method no longer works for sending a text message. Changing either the target SDK version or the device SDK version  makes it work. The logcat says nothing at all. Any idea why it isn't working?

```
    private void sendTextMessage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String phoneNumber = prefs.getString(KEY_USER_SELECTED_PHONE_NUMBER, getString(R.string.enter_phone_number_default_text));
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond

        intent.putExtra("sms_body", fetchTextMessageString());
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Utilities.showLogError(LOG_TAG, anfe, "Couldn't find SMS activity");
                showSnackbar(MainActivity.this, null, 4500, true, new SpannableString("No SMS app installed on your device"), false, "DISMISS", null);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I've found that I can fix this by adding this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

...but is there a more specific query I can use for sending text messages?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. I needed to add this to my manifest:

```
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Great find. But i think you need nothing of this all if you omit the resolver check `( if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()))`  and just start youir intent. Please try and report if you have time.

Comment: Great suggestion. I tried that and it works too. But what happens if the user's device doesn't have an SMS app?

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException ? You are the one that tests this all ;-)

Comment: Chances are youll end up adding it anyways. After migrating to Android 11 we had to add it for smsto, and also mailto scheme.