# Android App Call Intent to Default SMS App

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

My Android App uses an intent call with a couple of parameters to the default SMS App on the device thus;

```
    public void RequestSmsCode(String number, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            try{
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                DialogResult("SMS App not found", "Please use SMS App to request code");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This has worked absolutely fine up to and including Android 10, but on Android 11 nothing happens..!

My App *is not* an SMS sending App, this intent is only used for a registration procedure in lieu of building in SMS functionality, which isn't needed and complicates App distribution.

Something has changed in Android v11 and I haven't been able to spot it so far.

Question: Is there a quick way to get this working on all versions again..?

Well yes, reason being **"Package visibility in Android 11"**. Remove...

`if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)`

Seems a bit brutal though, makes me wonder why it was there in the first place, given there's no `else`, other than it being shown in multiple Android examples. Other ideas not tested yet...

This is quite good 'cos theoretically it fires up any default sms messaging app;

```
<manifest package="com.example.stuff">
...
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
...
</manifest>
```

This one would only fire Google's messaging app, you could add others.

```
<manifest package="com.example.stuff">
...
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.messaging" />
</queries>
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62535856.

Comment: Ooh ok, thanks @Mike_M, I'll give that a try

Comment: Oh, here's another query https://stackoverflow.com/q/64647782/ (didn't show up in my search)